# How do I get my Javascript function to use its input value correctly?

Tags: javascript, user-input

My function uses the first instance of var vLevel correctly, but returns an erroneously large value when vLevel is included again at the end.  If I substitute the second vLevel with the number 50, the function returns the correct values.  The input value is forcibly set to 50 for testing purposes only right now.

Here is my input section:

```
<th id='00'>Lv.<input id='iLevel' type='number' min='2' max='100' value= '50'></th>
```

relevant variable definition:

```
var vLevel = document.getElementById('iLevel').value;
```

and function:

```
function fHitPoints(baseStat, iv, ev, vLevel){
    return Math.floor((((baseStat*2 + iv + Math.floor(ev/4))*vLevel)/100) + vLevel + 10);
}
```

All other variables work fine.  If it helps, the function is part of the following loop:

```
var i = 0
var j = 0

while (j<17){
    while (i<4){
            if (i == 0) {
                table.rows[i+1].cells[j+1].innerHTML =
                fHitPoints(baseStat[j][i], iv[j][i], ev[j][i], vLevel);
                i++;
            } else {
            table.rows[i+1].cells[j+1].innerHTML =
            fStat(baseStat[j][i], iv[j][i], ev[j][i], vLevel, nature[j][i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    i = 0
    j++
}
```

fStat function:

```
function fStat(baseStat, iv, ev, vLevel, nature){
    return Math.floor((Math.floor(((baseStat*2 +
        iv + Math.floor(ev/4))*vLevel)/100) + 5)*nature);
```

Comment: Can you add your `fStat` function too? And are you updating HTML inside your `<th/>`

Comment: Sure thing.  Interestingly enough, vLevel works correctly no matter where/how many times I sub it in the fStat function. The table body contents are being updated.

Comment: I've checked the function output for a specific array value and it returns the same erroneous number; so the loop actually has nothing to do with it

Comment: Try getting the input object completely ( use "var vLevel = document.getElementById('iLevel');" ) in the variable definition and refer its value as vLevel.value later on. It is possible that you're loosing the reference through the way...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  fHitPoints gives the value 124 without the '+ vLevel + 10' portion.  It was literally taking 124 + 50 + 10 and returning 1245010.  I am extremely new to coding so I don't really know much about data types yet.

for some reason fStat does the math correctly but I think I can solve it from here.

Comment: Yes it makes sense. It happens in javascript. Some of your variables must be a string.

Comment: You should typecast your variables with Number. Number(vLevel). i.e.             fStat(baseStat[j][i], iv[j][i], ev[j][i], Number(vLevel), nature[j][i]);

Answer (score 0):

In the relevant variable definition:

```
var vLevel = document.getElementById('iLevel');
```

and in the functions' call use:

```
Number(vLevel.value)
```